# Troubles processing .docx template from rails to Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, jszip, docxtemplater

1. I am new on angular 4, I need to send a .docx template file from
   Angular(frontend) to rails(backend), and then when the user requires
   download the .docx template and processing using docxtemplater

   Here is my code to send the file from Angular to rails server:

   ```
   **component.ts**

   upload(event: any) 
     {
       const file = this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0];

       this.reportService.uploadfile(file, this.report.id, this.user.clinic.id).subscribe( res => {
         },error => {
           this.flashMessagesService.show('Error uploading the template. ', { classes: ['alert', 'alert-danger'], timeout: 5000 })
         })
       this.download_report(this.user.clinic.id, this.report.id);
     }
   **service.ts**
     public uploadfile(file : File,report_id: number, clinic_id: number): Observable<Response> 
     {
       const formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("report_id", report_id.toString());
       formData.append("clinic_id", clinic_id.toString());
       formData.append("report", file);
       let headers = this._tokenService.currentAuthHeaders;
       headers.delete('Content-Type');
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       return this._tokenService.request({
         method: 'post',
         url: environment.api_base + `/reports/uploadfile`,
         body: formData,
         headers: options.headers
       })
     }
   ```

   Here is my code to receive the file from Angular into rails server:

   ```
     # POST /reports/uploadfile/
     def uploadfile
       url = "#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id]
       dir = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id])
       FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)
       File.open(url, 'w+') do |f|
         f.write(params[:report].read.force_encoding('utf-8'))
       end
     end
   ```

   Here is my code to receive the file from rails to Angular:

   ```
       **component.ts**
   download_report(clinic_id: number ,report_id: number) 
     {
       this.reportService.downloadfile(clinic_id, report_id).subscribe( res => {
        var JSZip = require('jszip'); 
        var Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
         var zip = new JSZip();
         zip.file('file.docx',res['_body'],{binary: true});
         var doc = new Docxtemplater();
         doc.loadZip(zip);

         },error => {
           this.flashMessagesService.show('Error downloading the report. ', { classes: ['alert', 'alert-danger'], timeout: 5000 })
         })
     }


       **service.ts**
        public downloadfile(clinic_id: number,report_id: number ): any 
     {
       let params = {clinic_id: clinic_id, report_id: report_id}
       return this._tokenService.get('reports/downloadfile', {params: params});

      }
   ```

   Here is my code to send the file from rails to Angular:

   ```
     # GET /reports/downloadfile/
     def downloadfile
       @url = "#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id]
       send_file(@url,:filename => "report.doc", :type => 'application/msword')
     end
   ```

   The file was send fine, after being saved in the rails server in the
   disk, the file was opened using an editor and everything looks fine,
   then when the file was downloaded and was saved in the disk using
   saveAs(), the docx is opened fine that means that the file is
   received fine. But if before to save the file I try to process it
   with docxtemplater throws the following error inside the function
   doc.loadZip(zip);:

   ```
    core.es5.js:1084 ERROR XTInternalError {name: "InternalError", properties: {…}, message: "The filetype for this file could not be
   ```

   identified, is this file corrupted ?", stack: "Error: The filetype
   for this file could not be
   ide…(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61365:26)"}

   The response fron the rails server is :

   ```
   _body
   :
   "��ࡱ�;��  F���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� ↵����
    !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDE����G������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Root
   ```

   Entry������������������������������������������������������������������������   ↵
        !"#$%&'()*+,-./012345����789:;����=������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������↵���� �FMicrosoft
   Word-Dokument↵MSWordDocWord.Document.8�9�q%↵[d��dNormal$a$1$*$A$3B*OJQJCJmH sH KHPJnHtH^JaJ_H9.����.    WW8Num1z0OJQJ^J"���" WW8Num2z0"���"   WW8Num2z1"���!"   WW8Num2z2"���1"   WW8Num2z3"���A"   WW8Num2z4"���Q"   WW8Num2z5"���a"   WW8Num2z6"���q"   WW8Num2z7"����"   WW8Num2z8B����BAbsatz-StandardschriftartH����HWW-Absatz-StandardschriftartJ����JWW-Absatz-Standardschriftart1L����LWW-Absatz-Standardschriftart11.����.BulletsOJQJPJ^JF��FHeading
       ���x$OJ   QJ  CJPJ^JaJ.B�. Text Body↵��x /� List ^J↵@"@Caption
       !�x�x$CJ6^J↵aJ]&�"&Index"$^J↵4�24Table Contents#$>�1B>
       Table Heading$$a$$5\�����l��,b�$2��F'3TQ�g2@���2����(  �������↵���↵�↵��N����A?���������C"��������<↵�C����� �&�TPG�Times
   New Roman5�Symbol3&�Ariali�Liberation SerifTimes New
   Romani��Liberation SerifTimes New Roman?��DejaVu Sans?��Lohit
   Hindi5�Symbol_��OpenSymbolArial Unicode MSS&��Liberation
   SansArial?��Lohit HindiB��hH�Grbg��'
   …¯�~�A~�o|�~�I>�ޟ�~~�͗�_�7{Ư3�����|Z7��{!���~�I<�V��{8�OO��/͗³�wgh���/�!�Ľ�����yb��(uB_�2�GV��C�}��G�Ư�0���|�{�w�]��+��+�䳽|7���_�M�I��GN����5�����n�0���n��������<�/>Q��̯���c?�ÿ�W��ao�~��W�w��[oǿ�ֿ�7��3�3O���N�?`�XC�]?����Ư�$������l�������i���O����/>�����.��k>�����/Ľ���7�/>�^��˟�����~Z��|�}������͟��-�z_F^Zt�0d8hk�]%WK&����Քa/�~��K��E߷7TX2   �ߴ袥�Χ����)�Ԣ��P�a��hqH�ҢN��b���E��j���d�ZtȰ�Pa�:ԥE��↵�ߒyh����a����MZ�>*ÐajѦE�}S[��Ya�o?F/Z��0WC���C�Y|�n2L-ڴ�3��f�g�ᠭu��ߴ�;3�jh�e
   Ðaj�b���Ӿ--�|N��dZ�i�-��t�v؇j�H�T2ɥԷ�HӢM�>��-���ߔaj�灐�����C�%���M�>kk��d�aȰ7�9Z��0WC�!�>�:e��>�+��ah�EK7�d�:lSZ��0WC��E�c�0�m�����20�)�Pm����X�%���M�Ǧ�oZ���o�0���@�����@��Ih��E�s5d�Z���V}��6�$�WR2I-����-�~Ӣ-l�&WC�/�S�ÕT��mi��sB�%���M�6-����iQ'�\
       �mZt�ܸ߾���,znS2Y�a�)�Ԣ�{K�6-�M�~ӢEZt��ߔah��E��0$9Z�i�"�d�:lSZ�i���
       ����o�3a�Q�K}����-Ӂ���R_�~`��}��U�E�����K}�E:n�W森���4�k8L�i��x`:�:�
   ��<���|��I��_����������b�����(Vyi���s���p3/��a�}��_��,�І�@�R_��I��s��U�E��U�EXա���<�tܮLO.�ɴ�ܛ����|��<L�i�*�"�a�jK�R_���tr:���~i5u�C�EX�iH�l�2X��<�u��c}>,�}��|��Ӻ7磞�a�O�(Vy�
       ��a���2$�]!�>ٯ��~��!�:�U�E��U�EXա���<��j��w|B�����0�gL�
       ����G��U��T�~��d��틽ai��yԫ|(����޽��Q��a�;y�_��ě,�~��jW��t״ι��>9S�j�ko����
       �5�1�}R��+����1ӫ0���y�'���'��U>�w~�x��C��{_<jhý���wm'�*����t��:T{o���@NN��a�L�a˽�ʽ��r���6�L�}�ts��U��6�}��Խ}>$�~H�pul8��/
       c�N��}>���Uݫ|50X�ߛ�{7���@�ìo��jWy:���_�����t~:|o��7O����  ����7�[Vu�>�ծ��'{g�V'��   �Wý��{��+Ǿ����^���.�A�Y��M�xSIaZ�a���>9S�jO�T�E����
       ��A[��j��O2Y�Rm�ʳH�����gmam:3��~W^�I�ì�dPyiߖJ�HC{�v҃��|�y�2����ːT�]yyxc��χ�j�y�$�Է�TSI�d=�<�t3OC{
   'W��K7�>}>�<m/�R%Y�>T�EʥTI�
   ����I����J�.���U�ηg�mi�Ő��~���bH�vo*ɢ�jjQ'�~i���,���0�\
       �і]��|�K��,R�*�"�R�$�t���Ő��6޴�2�'e�]�頍zX-��0V�>/�d��v�j*�"���g�n�o�V��gV77;~����U�!�v���X�d�.K��d�Z4KC�jƢ.-����a��ݳ�U_;�ս����}6}íޅC�듪��R�gC��6�Yա���!�v���i7�������{�t�WL�L�/��y�'���'{C��R���y��n>Đ��N����x�ͼ<�����������0��{C^�*O���r�x�V���Z?������al���!a��f��x��>Y�iu�*O}��>I_�Ӑ|�!�]��0,�o��U^j`:�z�3u:N��Vy�Vo�+g���î4�ծ�t܆}RjiuH�O�6N�p��
       y��<�O������X�ﵵ�J�KaW�'��>L��9gHV�|� ��W��3G�<�
       ����o��m���Xl_g����y��'g�P�{ːW�������~ �j�|oX�ۏ#n�χd���t���>�z��i�1�y,
       �~��@:�:�i������:�y+���j��S��tc�}^u��,�ІaW�}��wsK���}^�>�ֽ!�v�����͙�i�]�@�}>����ua������,��|��zu�*/}����4�U�a8h��'�:�>OCҷ�:�>OCXu_�����R�c{50��Ûu}��m�ZgVy�����"��Wn�E�ih�j�x�q�I���!}އ�:�y�0�[����U����L�ܻ��ZZ�9���ϫ�ðj�{�ɽ��(�.7�U��Q��>,�I�;���vZG��i���w�}^W��B���+f��6m�y�V����E]�u�Y��
       }��C��E�
       f��v��Ԣφ�lKK;ma[�S�����
       9��0dX*̢L�^K�V3�=�hӢ-��"����&�9�Z�ه9Y*�"��L*�6exR��h��f;hk�33��3��^I�n���0�M�mZ�Y[�X�6|lش~ӢM�fGeRy�)�TI�U�3u��Wa�o���M-�m�Z�l'}h�n2WS�>��S�e��R?�a�:Ða�0�TK�W���ctז�v��bK�>?Dڰ�d�C�)���)R�>�U}s
   �u�6�!Cҷ��L�������,9Z��\
       ��fRy&!�A-���3�↵�H�Ty�o?Fwmi�Ő��6���a�޶�iѦO�����E]��N[�=Dj��j��jS���ʫg�m��,R�nSc�Zԅ����mZ�¾�v4-�LôZ���M���K����C_�H-ڴ����f�*�<���`X�6�hӢ�'�}�Iȶ7�5Vy&!����~)��3   پ�7��x���~˷;���ާ�.��t=�{
       ���~�yν���wz齍����F3|���Oy�7�O�]���z��6z/��?�{k�Mo��{?   /?�[����)-�����>�wy˧�+�T�--����ݻ�oz�����Ix!�1�jW�\�Wp�^  ��{%W�� ?��^��W�x.n����W�V�����^ ����Y�w�u�Y����h�gm��!�Ԣ��P�a��hqH�����n*�"
       m��?d]a�o?F/Zt�0�M}
       ��R�)����y���>���>����0ͧ�j 
       �q�Ӫ��p&�V5�K��0\�W{o^ؘ�>)�ޕa���������>�/p5�N^��� �2$�n��d��'��(�g��݇�ECr܆��A>�<���>�/p5�����e�*�{`c.��2���U�������y�癬�xo��BYu�g�~`�wj�ڷG�:d�I°��o���~�Lޛ�aޞ�g�qM��:Ða�:Ðaii�-ܳqhC΄�3�↵�(�$��R�Քm�:�^���3��3�↵��MC���ȅ���I��Y.���|�����\>#��p��o��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�r��ʽ�+�J��+�����?��6.,��IEND�B`�Root
   Entry��������   �F�CompObj����jOle↵��������1Table�������������SummaryInformation(����6DWordDocument���������uObjectPool����������������DocumentSummaryInformation8������������

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to send the file from Angular to rails server:

```
    **component.ts**

    upload(event: any) 
      {
        const file = this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0];

        this.reportService.uploadfile(file, this.report.id, this.user.clinic.id).subscribe( res => {
          },error => {
            this.flashMessagesService.show('Error uploading the template. ', { classes: ['alert', 'alert-danger'], timeout: 5000 })
          })
        this.download_report(this.user.clinic.id, this.report.id);
      }
    **service.ts**
      public uploadfile(file : File,report_id: number, clinic_id: number): Observable<Response> 
      {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("report_id", report_id.toString());
        formData.append("clinic_id", clinic_id.toString());
        formData.append("report", file);
        let headers = this._tokenService.currentAuthHeaders;
        headers.delete('Content-Type');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._tokenService.request({
          method: 'post',
          url: environment.api_base + `/reports/uploadfile`,
          body: formData,
          headers: options.headers
        })
      }
```

Here is my code to receive the file from Angular into rails server:

```
      # POST /reports/uploadfile/
      def uploadfile
        url = "#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id]
        dir = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id])
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)
        File.open(url, 'w+') do |f|
          f.write(params[:report].read.force_encoding('utf-8'))
        end
      end
```

Here is my code to receive the file from rails to Angular:

```
        **component.ts**
    download_report(clinic_id: number ,report_id: number) 
      {
        this.reportService.downloadfile(clinic_id, report_id).subscribe( res => {
 var JSZip = require('jszip'); 
 var Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
 var file = new File([res],'report.doc',{type:'application/msword'});
 let reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 reader.onload = () => {
  this.doc = {
    filename: file.name,
    filetype: file.type,
    //To encode base64 (.docx does not work)
     value: reader.result
  };

  var zip = new JSZip(this.doc.value);
  var doc = new Docxtemplater();
  doc.loadZip(zip);
  doc.setData({
    nombre: 'John'
    });
  try 
  {
    doc.render()
  }
  catch (error) 
  {
    var e = { message: error.message, name: error.name, stack: error.stack, properties: error.properties}
    throw error;
  }

  var buf = doc.getZip().generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});
  var out = doc.getZip().generate({ type:"blob", mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"}); //Output the document using Data-URI
  saveAs(out,"output.docx");
 }

},error => {
    this.flashMessagesService.show('Error downloading the report. ', { classes: ['alert', 'alert-danger'], timeout: 5000 })
})
      }


        **service.ts**
         public downloadfile(clinic_id: number,report_id: number ): any 
      {
           let params = {clinic_id: clinic_id, report_id: report_id}
return this._tokenService.get('reports/downloadfile', {params: params, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}).map(
  (res) => { return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/msword' })})

       }
```

Here is my code to send the file from rails to Angular:

```
      # GET /reports/downloadfile/
      def downloadfile
        @url = "#{Rails.root}/reports/" + params[:clinic_id] + "/template/" + params[:report_id]
        send_file(@url,:filename => "report.doc", :type => 'application/msword')
      end
```